# Page not found 404 - Django

Tags: python, django, http, http-status-code-404, get-request

I'm a newbie to Django and I know this probably has been asked alot of times.

So basically what's happening is when I try to create a new project and whenever I'm trying to run my server, by default it's opening **http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/** and not **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**.

Even if I run the server with my other projects, I'm facing the same error.

I followed this django basics tutorial on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/skeleton_website

Idk but somehow I think it's default address is set to **http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/**.

Here's the link to the repo for the project:
https://github.com/Fanceh/django-404-error

Here's my project's urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from testuapp import urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include("testuapp.urls"))
]
```

Here's the code in my testuapp urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.testu),
]
```

Here's my webapp's views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def testu(request):
    render(request, 'Greetings!')
```

Is there any way I can change it?

Regards

Comment: So us your urls.py from the project

Comment: Here I added it

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial link it mentions the redirect.
Any request for the root URL, will redirect you to /catalog.

Screenshot from the tutorial below.

HTH

[image: Redirect from tutorial]

Comment: but it's a different project, I didn't add any catalog urls to this one. I used this catalog on previous project which I already deleted.

Comment: Can you post urls.py from your webapp testuapp.urls?

Comment: I added it on the post

Comment: Can you post a link to the project? A repo where we could inspect the code? 
Looking at what you have posted Vansh there doesn't seem be a problem. But there is a redirect, generally speaking urls.py would be the place.

Comment: Im'ma add a repo! Thanks Mustafa

Comment: https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/appendix_django.html
Please follow tthis url. 
Also please mark this answer as done

Comment: There I added a repo

Answer (score 0):

so i assume you are below url pattern structure in your testuapp project.

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('catalog',include("views.catalog"))
]
```

views.calalog is the name of the method in your view file.

Comment: I never used any views.catalog in my new project. It was a webapp from my previous project. I'll still add the views.py of my new project.

Comment: so as per my understanding you don't have idea about the Django project structure first clear that still you face any issue. you can ask.

Comment: I'm just facing the problem on port 8000. It's not that I don't know my Django project structure but like I said whenever I try to run any project, it loads up the http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/ and not http://127.0.0.1:8000/. And also I never used any views.catalog here

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out, it's just the chrome cache. I cleared it and bam it's working!

Comment: bam I just opened another browser and it still not working.